# Problem with going idle and active with jquery: when active update useronline timestamp on mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, timer, idle-timer

I want to update the timestamp on useronline database only when people aren't idle (keyboard mouse active for some time-I am using a jquery plugin for that) The problem for me is that I can't clear the interval for the function so in my test script below, when it starts counting it never stops and even when active again it starts another counter so that its like its counting twice as fast. How am I supposed to stop that timer? Its like the counter has never been started when its idle- so it can't find it to stop it.

In the real script the counter will be $.get()-ing the php that updates the mysql table. For that reason i'm using intervals, or it would get on every mouse move right? and that would be loading the server.

http://jsbin.com/uleza5 to test just don't move mouse for 6 seconds then see the idle text, then move the mouse and it will start counting; after 6 seconds it will go idle again when inactive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="js/jquery_plugin_timer2.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-idletimer/raw/master/jquery.idle-timer.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>timertest</title>
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.status').html('active');
});

x = 0;
function count() { 
        x+=1;
        $('.usercount').html(x);
        }

(function() {

    var timeout = 6000;
  var it;
    $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function() {
    clearInterval(it);    
        $('.status').html('idle');
    });


    $(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function() {
      var it = setInterval(count, 1000);
     $('.status').html('active');
    });
   $.idleTimer(timeout);

})(jQuery);

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="status" style="border:1px dashed black; width:500px; height:50px;"></div>
<div class="usercount"style="border:1px dashed black; width:500px; height:50px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your issue is with the timings, its because your not clearing the interval's right. The variable it is being set and used where it is undefined or out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="js/jquery_plugin_timer2.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-idletimer/raw/master/jquery.idle-timer.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>timertest</title>
<script language="javascript">
var it;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.status').html('active');
});

x = 0;
function count() { 
        x+=1;
        $('.usercount').html(x);
        }

(function() {

    var timeout = 6000;

    $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function() {
    clearInterval(it);    
        $('.status').html('idle');
    });


    $(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function() {
      it = setInterval(count, 1000);
     $('.status').html('active');
    });
   $.idleTimer(timeout);

})(jQuery);

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="status" style="border:1px dashed black; width:500px; height:50px;"></div>
<div class="usercount"style="border:1px dashed black; width:500px; height:50px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```